# CakePHP3 - component Flash not working

Tags: cakephp, flash-message

In my app controller:

```
class AppController extends Controller
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->loadComponent('Cookie');
    }
```

}

In provider controller function review:

```
public function review() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $userId = $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.UserId');
            $partnerId = $this->request->data('PartnerId');
            $content = $this->request->data('Content');
            $commentTable = TableRegistry::get('Comment');
            $comment = $commentTable->newEntity();
            $comment->UserId = $userId;
            $comment->PartnerId = $partnerId;
            $comment->Content = $content;
            $comment->CreatedBy = $userId;
            $comment->UpdatedBy = $userId;
            $comment->Source = $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.LoginBy');
            if ($commentTable->save($comment)) {
                $this->Flash->success('Thank you for review!');
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error('So Sorry your review was failed! Please notify for us to fixed this problem!');
            }
            $this->redirect('provider/' . $partnerId);
        }
    }
```

- When user submit review success but flash doesn't show. However, I try to create another project follow tutorial from youtube(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eASSNS1f3V4) for test and Flash working in this project.
- Sorry about my english, please help me. Thank you very much!

Comment: plz check on this url http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/flash.html

Comment: Thank you @Tonystark, I resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

This is my fault because I don't understand cake clearly. I changed defaut layout of Cake so when Flash call HTML in folder Element/Flash/**.ctp with out cake style css. So the message box doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm that's not an answer to your question but here is a few tips to improve your code:

```
    public function review(){
        if($this->request->is('post')){
            $commentTable = TableRegistry::get('Comment');
            $comment = $CommentTable->newEntity();
            $userId = $this->Auth->user('id');
            $comment->patchEntity($comment, $this->request->data);      
            $comment->patchEntity($comment, ['CreatedBy' => $userId, 'UserId' => $userId, 'UpdatedBy' => $userId, 'Source' => $userId]);
            if($commentTable->save($comment)){
                //something
            } else {
                //something
            }
        }
    }
```

You can put all the form's variable in the entity in one time if you use the same column name for your form input by doing this line:

```
$comment->patchEntity($comment, $this->request->data);
```

If you want to access to the user session variables in your controller, you can use this:

```
$userId = $this->Auth->user('id');
```

Then if you want to put other variable in your entity manually, you can do like this:

```
$comment->patchEntity($comment, ['CreatedBy' => $userId, 'UserId' => $userId, 'UpdatedBy' => $userId, 'Source' => $userId]);
```

Hope it will help you